# when rebuiding jar file for vtd-xml, build.bat throws errors such as "java_cup\parser.java:695: package java_cup.runtime does not exist"

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I am getting errors like this for almost all files trying to be compiled. Due to this, none of the class files are being created and thus the jar is unusable.

Any suggestions?

I didn't change the build.bat file at all but here it is anyway.

```
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\*.java
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\xpath\*.java
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\parser\*.java
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\transcode\*.java
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\extended\*.java
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\extended\xpath\*.java
javac -target 1.6 com\ximpleware\extended\parser\*.java
javac -target 1.6 java_cup\*.java
javac -target 1.6 java_cup\runtime\*.java

jar -cvf vtd-xml.jar com\ximpleware\*.class com\ximpleware\xpath\*.class com\ximpleware\parser\*.class com\ximpleware\transcode\*.class java_cup\*.class java_cup\runtime\*.class com\ximpleware\extended\*.class com\ximpleware\extended\xpath\*.class com\ximpleware\extended\parser\*.class

del/S *.class
```

All of proposed paths are there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but this may help:
remove below lines

```
javac -target 1.6 java_cup\*.java
javac -target 1.6 java_cup\runtime\*.java
```

and instead try using:

```
javac -target 1.6 java_cup\*.java java_cup\runtime\*.java
```

Answer (score 1):

figured it out...

just had to add the folder where the buil.bat file was to my %CLASSPATH% env variable